# OSMGeoAdmin shows textarea for PointField

Tags: django-admin, geodjango

Here is my model:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    location = models.PointField(geography=True, dim=6, srid=4326, null=True)
```

I've registered it in the admin

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from project.accounts.models import CustomUser

admin.site.register(CustomUser, admin.OSMGeoAdmin)
```

But still got textarea for this field.
[image]

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [documented way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#putting-your-data-on-the-map):

> GeoDjango also supplements the Django admin by allowing users to
>   create and modify geometries on a JavaScript slippy map (powered by
>   OpenLayers).

in your `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from project.accounts.models import CustomUser

admin.site.register(CustomUser, admin.GeoModelAdmin)
```

and don't forget your `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```